# C++ Program stops working when attribuing values to dynamic array of struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm having trouble running a code I've been assigned to modify.

The code works normally, but I've been asked to test one of the functions from the code, so I made a set of data that I'd give the function to test that the outputs will be the desired ones.

However, whenever I run my code, a message box appears that says that the program has stopped working.

Here's the beginning of the code:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nrMonsters;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    Monsters *monster[20]={0};


cout<<"Beginning of Test\n...\n";
//the first data set prepared for testing
Monsters *date1[4]= {0};

//date1 - CC BB AA DD
date1[0]->name="CC";
date1[1]->name="BB";
date1[2]->name="AA";
date1[3]->name="DD";
  for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
  {
     date1[a]->type=BALAUR;
     date1[a]->health=10;
  }
cout<<"Set date1 initialised.";

cout<<"\n\nSorting set date1...\t";
sortMonster(4,date1);
```

Here's what the structure is:

```
    enum MonsterTypes
{
    UNDEFINED=-1,
    VARCOLAC,
    CAPCAUN,
    PAIANJEN,
    SPIRIDUS,
    STRIGOI,
    BALAUR
};

struct Monsters
{
    MonsterTypes type;
    std::string name;
    int health;
};
```

Here's the requirements of the function (it's meant to sort them alphabetically):

```
    void sortMonster(int number_of_monsters, Monsters **monster)
{
/    /sorting
}
```

When I hover the mouse above the second argument, it shows 
"Monster **monster"
But when I hover it at the top of the code where it's initialised, it reads
"Monster *mosnter[]"

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: `Monsters *monster[20]` you never allocate memory for any of these pointers.

Comment: `date1` is an array of four null pointers. That you dereference. Leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: either create `Monsters variables` and make the pointers point those objects (if static objects are needed) else allocated memory for each pointer in array and access the elements of array (if dynamic objects are needed - Here don't forgot to free/delete them after its last usage)

Comment: You don't have a "dynamic array" in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory.

```
Monsters *date1 = new Monsters[4];
```

Or use C style [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Dont forget to free allocated memory via

```
delete []date1;
```

or

```
free(date1); // if allocated with malloc/calloc
```

Comment: Don't recommend using `malloc` on `Monsters`. Using `malloc` to allocate array of those, would lead to undefined behavior (due to have `std::string` as a member, and the fact that `malloc` doesn't call constructors).